# Including a shared library in a go build

Tags: go, sciter

How can I include an SO file when I build for linux? With windows I simply put the dll in the same folder but that did not work with the linux build. In particular, I am building a go sciter project and need to include the `libsciter-gtk-64.so` in the executable/package.

Comment: Adding a dll to the source folder does not build it into the binary. Please show what exactly you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

My way of solving this was to use an additional tool, which had the added benefit of an optional desktop file and other metadata. AppImage solves the library problem, all I had to do was create an AppImage with the so files in /usr/lib/ and build through their command.

Answer (score 0):

@Robert's solution is nice. One could also place the *.so file in the same directory as the executable and create a start.sh script with the line:

```sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(dirname "$0")" "$(dirname "$0")/your_executable"
```